# How to access subparts of a Three.js JSON mesh?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have a model that I exported from Blender in the Three.js JSON format. I have it loading correctly in a browser. The model is of a control panel with buttons, switches, etc. Each of these buttons and switches is a subpart of the mesh. How do I access these subparts(to make the switches move and such)?

Comment: I would try to name these parts in blender and then see if the names persist in json. If they do then you can traverse the model to find the parts you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In Blender, each part is named. When I do the export, and examine the exported js file, I can't see any of those named parts. There is just the metadata, the materials, and then a huge list of vertices.

Comment: In this case I dont see how you can access the parts you want.

Comment: You could check the `scene` option in the three.js exporter. It might break your existing pipeline though

Comment: I think I need to export in a different format. I think this one has lost the information for the different subparts. It looks like clara.io will export Three.js objects. I will try that.

Comment: I have figured this out. A better way to handle this process is to export from Clara.IO. Export in the ThreeJS Scene format and load using THREE.ObjectLoader like so: var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader(); loader.load("MyModel.json", modelLoadCallback); By doing it this way, the the model's hierarchy is preserved.